# Using PowerShell to convert XML to HTML

Tags: xml, powershell

I have an XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='file:///C:/Program%20Files/Application/log_format.xsl'?>
<!DOCTYPE log [<!ENTITY data SYSTEM 'data/20130408.dat'>]>
<log xmlns="runtime:log">&data;</log>
```

The xsl file transforms it into HTML. I can't open the file in IE just fine and view the expected results. I would like to via a PowerShell script convert this in plain HTML. How would I go about that?

Comment: http://devio.wordpress.com/2009/09/15/command-line-xslt-processor-with-powershell/

Comment: With some explanation, the above comment should be an answer; possibly the accepted answer (since it doesn't depend upon loading an extra module).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This [blog entry](http://devio.wordpress.com/2009/09/15/command-line-xslt-processor-with-powershell/) has a code snippet that should work.  It uses the `System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform` .NET class to do the XSL transformation.  The rest is just for getting the input and displaying the output.

This was originally a comment, but I guess I'll make it an answer so it's easier for other people who are searching for a solution.

Comment: perfect solution, no code, just pointing to the right direction :)

Answer (score 2):

The [PowerShell Community Extensions](http://pscx.codeplex.com) has a `Convert-Xml` that will do an XSL transform on the XML.  If the resulting file isn't valid HTML then you need to work on the XSL file.

Comment: The link does not exist anymore

Comment: The module can be obtained here: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Pscx

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return an xml object instead of writing the output to file so you can do more in-line activities. this will work. in addition i split the creation of the processor into a separate function so that you can create it once and re-use which is more memory friendly.

```
function Invoke-TransformXML($path,$styleSheetPath,$output,$parameters, $compiledtransform)
{
  if( ! (test-path $path )) { Throw"XML input file not found: $path"}

  $path = resolve-path $path

  if ( ! (Test-Path $compiledtransform))
    { 
      if( ! ($compiledtransform.GetType() -eq [System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform] )) 
      { 
        $ctType = $compiledtransform.GetType() ;
        Throw "Compiled transform is wrong type: $ctType" 
      }
      else
      {
        $xslt = $compiledtransform
      }
    }

  if (($compiledtransform -eq $null) )
  {
    if( ! (test-path $styleSheetPath )   ) { Throw"XSL template file not found: $styleSheetPath"}
    $styleSheetPath = Resolve-Path $styleSheetPath

    $xslt = Get-CompiledTransform $styleSheetPath
  }

  $transformed = New-Object System.IO.MemoryStream

  try
  {
      $xslt.Transform([string]$path, [System.Xml.Xsl.XsltArgumentList]$arglist, [System.IO.Stream]$transformed)
      $transformed.Position = 0
      #$reader = New-Object System.Xml.XmlTextReader($ms)
      $outdoc = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
      $outdoc.Load($transformed)
      # close stream, we are done with it
      $transformed.Close()
      return $outdoc
  } Finally {
    $transformed.Close()
  }
}

function Get-CompiledTransform($styleSheetPath)
{

  if( ! (test-path $styleSheetPath )   ) { Throw"XSL template file not found: $styleSheetPath"}
  $styleSheetPath = Resolve-Path $styleSheetPath


  if( [System.Diagnostics.Debugger]::IsAttached )
  {
    $xslt = New-Object System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform( $true )
  }
  else
  {
    $xslt = New-Object System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform( $false )
  }

  $arglist = new-object System.Xml.Xsl.XsltArgumentList

  foreach( $param in $parms )
  {
    if ($parms.Name)
    {
        $paramName = $parms.Name
        $paramNamespaceUri = $parms.NamespaceUri
        $paramValue = $parms.Value
        $arglist.AddParam($paramName, $paramNamespaceUri, $paramValue)
    }
  }

  $xsltSettings = New-Object System.Xml.Xsl.XsltSettings($false,$true)
  $xslt.Load($styleSheetPath, $xsltSettings, (New-Object System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver))

  return $xslt
}
```